# Add/Subtract two pyspark CountVectorizer sparse vector columns

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-mllib, countvectorizer

I would like to take the difference of CountVectorizer transformed pairs of docs. In other words, take the diff between two columns of sparse vectors. I am applying the same transformer to df[doc1] and df[doc2], so the dimensions of the resulting vector pairs (df['X1'] - df['X2']) will always be consistent.

```py
from pyspark.ml.feature import RegexTokenizer, CountVectorizer
from pyspark.ml import Pipeline
from pyspark.sql.functions import col

df = spark.createDataFrame([("homer likes donuts".split(" "), "donuts taste delicious".split(" "), 0),
                            ("five by five boss".split(" "), "five is a number".split(" "), 1)],
                            ["words1", "words2", "label"])

display(df)

cv = CountVectorizer()

union_words = df.select(col('words1').alias('words')).union(df.select(col('words2').alias('words')))

cv = CountVectorizer() \
      .setInputCol('words') \
      .fit(union_words)

df = cv.setInputCol('words1') \
        .setOutputCol('X1') \
        .transform(df)

df = cv.setInputCol('words2') \
        .setOutputCol('X2') \
        .transform(df)

display( df )
```

```
X1                         X2
[0,11,[1,2,9],[1,1,1]]     [0,11,[1,4,8],[1,1,1]]
[0,11,[0,3,10],[2,1,1]]    [0,11,[0,5,6,7],[1,1,1,1]]
```

I can't add columns (column type mismatch, requires numeric or calendarinterval). And I tried @zero323's [add function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32983951/11904206), but get at assert error at isinstance(v1, SparseVector)

```
df.withColumn("result", (col("X1") + col("X2"))
df.withColumn("result", add(col("X1"), col("X2"))
```

In sparse vector format I expect the results to be:

```
[0,11,[2,4,8,9],[1,-1,-1,1]]
[0,11,[0,3,5,6,7,10],[1,1,-1,-1,-1,1]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Needed to convert the function into a udf with return type VectorUDT. Solved by combining solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32983951/11904206) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54604791/11904206).

```py
import numpy as np
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
from pyspark.ml.linalg import SparseVector, Vectors, VectorUDT
from pyspark.ml.feature import RegexTokenizer, CountVectorizer
from pyspark.ml import Pipeline
from pyspark.sql.functions import col

df = spark.createDataFrame(data=[("homer likes donuts".split(" "), ["donuts", "taste", "delicious"], 0),
                            (["five", "by", "five", "boss"], ["five", "is", "a", "number"], 1)],
                            schema=["words1", "words2", "label"])


cv = CountVectorizer()

union_words = df.select(col('words1').alias('words')).union(df.select(col('words2').alias('words')))

cv = CountVectorizer() \
      .setInputCol('words') \
      .fit(union_words)

df = cv.setInputCol('words1') \
          .setOutputCol('X1') \
          .transform(df)

df = cv.setInputCol('words2') \
          .setOutputCol('X2') \
          .transform(df)

@udf(VectorUDT())
def minus(v1, v2):
    # Sparse vector will become dense
    assert isinstance(v1, SparseVector) and isinstance(v2, SparseVector)
    assert v1.size == v2.size 
    # Compute union of indices
    indices = set(v1.indices).union(set(v2.indices))
    # Not particularly efficient but we are limited by SPARK-10973
    # Create index: value dicts
    v1d = dict(zip(v1.indices, v1.values))
    v2d = dict(zip(v2.indices, v2.values))
    zero = np.float64(0)
    # Create dictionary index: (v1[index] - v2[index])
    values =  {i: v1d.get(i, zero) - v2d.get(i, zero)
               for i in indices
               if v1d.get(i, zero) - v2d.get(i, zero) != zero}
    return Vectors.sparse(v1.size, values)

df = df.withColumn('NAME_X_DIFF', minus('X1', 'X2'))
display(df)
```

```
+----------------------+--------------------------+-----+---------------------------+--------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------+
|words1                |words2                    |label|X1                         |X2                              |X_DIFF                                         |
+----------------------+--------------------------+-----+---------------------------+--------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------+
|[homer, likes, donuts]|[donuts, taste, delicious]|0    |(11,[1,4,10],[1.0,1.0,1.0])|(11,[1,3,5],[1.0,1.0,1.0])      |(11,[3,4,5,10],[-1.0,1.0,-1.0,1.0])            |
|[five, by, five, boss]|[five, is, a, number]     |1    |(11,[0,6,9],[2.0,1.0,1.0]) |(11,[0,2,7,8],[1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0])|(11,[0,2,6,7,8,9],[1.0,-1.0,1.0,-1.0,-1.0,1.0])|
+----------------------+--------------------------+-----+---------------------------+--------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------+
```